# Cuidarse in Spanish

Tags: gramática, vocabulario

I'm reading a story called *Cuenta ratones* by [Ellen Stoll Walsh](https://www.amazon.es/Cuenta-ratones-Ellen-Stoll-Walsh/dp/9681637666). However, I don't understand the following phrase.

> *Se cuidaban de las serpientes.*

**Context**

> Un esplendoroso día varios ratones se divertían en el campo.
> Cautelosos, **se cuidaban de las serpientes**. Pero cuando les dio sueño
> se olvidaron de ellas y se echaron una siesta.

I get that they are saying that the rats were wary of the snakes, but it feels like they are saying that the rats took care of the snakes.

What does *"Se cuidaban de los serpientes."* mean?

and when would you use *cuidarse* as oppose to *cuidar*?

Comment: Are you talking about this book by Ellen Stoll Walsh? https://www.amazon.es/Cuenta-ratones-Ellen-Stoll-Walsh/dp/9681637666 Please edit your question with the author of the refererred story or book.

Comment: "Se cuidaban de las serpientes" -- translate as "they protected themselves from the snakes"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have understood the text perfectly and I can see why you find it a bit difficult.

When in doubt, you should check the Diccionario de la Real Academia Española de la Lengua, the DRAE. There you'll find that the verb [**cuidar**](https://dle.rae.es/cuidar) has the two meanings that you have pointed out: to take care of (2) and to be wary of (5).

> **cuidar**
> 2. tr. Asistir, guardar, conservar
> 5. **prnl**. Vivir con advertencia respecto de algo.

Let's discuss the difference between them with examples.

2 - take care
EN - They take care of the snakes in the zoo
ES - Cuidan de las serpientes en el zoo

5 - be wary
EN - The mice were wary of the snakes
ES - Los ratones **se** cuidaban de las serpientes.

Notice that I have highlighted **prnl** in my quote of the dictionary and **se** in my second example. **prnl** means that the verb is **pronominal**.

If we check the dictionary again

> [verbo pronominal](https://dle.rae.es/verbo#5TVOxkC)
>
> 1. m. Gram. verbo que se construye en todas sus formas con **pronombres reflexivos** átonos que no desempeñan ninguna función sintáctica y que concuerdan con el sujeto; p. ej., me arrepentí, se levantó.

When we use such verbs, they are accompanied by a **reflexive pronoun** that has no syntax functionality, **se** in your example.

Comment: "Cuidan de las serpientes en el zoo" -- That reads to me like "They care **from** the serpents at the zoo". I would instead remove "de" for the intended meaning: "Cuidan las serpientes en el zoológico."

Comment: @JoL "Cuidan las serpientes en el zoologico" makes it sound like the snakes are the ones taking care of something

Comment: Perhaps "En el zoológico cuidan **a** las serpientes."

Comment: @sbell No, that'd be "Las serpientes cuidan ...". You know, subject before verb. In "cuidan las serpientes", the serpents are the object in the sentence.

Comment: @sbell: definitely not.  "¿Qué hacen Laura y José? Cuidan las serpientes en el zoológico."

Comment: @sbell: definitely not.  "¿Qué hacen Laura y José? Cuidan las serpientes en el zoológico." If the snakes are taking care of something at the zoo, your sentence is not saying what it is, making the sentence not mean what you say. "Cuidan las serpientes en el zoológico a sus crías" is probably technically correct, but it sounds super weird; people would instead say "Las serpientes cuidan a sus crías en el zóologico", or "En el zoológico, las serpientes cuidan a sus crías".

Comment: For meaning (2), it might be better to say "take care of" (or care for) rather than "take care".  In English, if you are caring for something other than yourself, you would typically use a preposition to introduce the thing you are caring for.  Without the preposition, it would usually mean "take care (of yourself)", as when you say "Take care!" at the end of a conversation.  Meaning (5), 'be wary', can also be expressed as "take care" if you include the thing to avoid.  "Take care you don't step on glass!"  or, in your example, "The mice took care to not be discovered by snakes."

Answer (score 1):

> I get that they are saying that the rats were wary of the snakes, but it feels like they are saying that the rats took care of the snakes.

Well, look to the reflexive pronoun *se* here. If the rats were taking care of the snakes, we might say that ***les** cuidaban* — "they guarded **them**." But instead we're saying that the rats ***se** cuidaban* — "they guarded **themselves.**"

They guarded themselves (*se cuidaban*) against (*de*) what? Against the snakes (*de las serpientes*).

A similar use of the reflexive verb *cuidarse* would be if I told you *¡Cuidate de las serpientes!* — "Guard yourself against the snakes!" or colloquially, "Watch out for snakes!"

If you wanted to say that the rats *took care of* the snakes, you'd say *los ratones cuidaban a las serpientes*; if you were talking about the snakes like they were real human people you'd say *los ratones **les** cuidaban a las serpientes*. Notice the change from *cuidar de* (guarding "away from") to *cuidar a* (guarding "toward"), which metaphorically matches the rats' posture in re the snakes.

By the way, if you wanted to say that the rats *took care of* the snakes while being faithful to [the ambiguous English meaning of "take care of"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9LbKWL7GRA), you might say that *los ratones se encargaron de las serpientes,* which says something like "the rats (took charge of/took on/took responsibility for) the snakes," without being overly specific about what responsibility we're talking about here, exactly. (But I'm not super confident about this paragraph. I should have paid more attention to the subtitles in *Breaking Bad*. Anyone feel like leaving a comment to correct me? ;))

---

UPDATE after a well-intentioned but sense-changing edit by someone else: It appears that my use of *les* above may be a case of [leísmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le%C3%ADsmo) and may vary by region/dialect/training. (I am a non-native speaker who learned in high school in the eastern U.S.) Anyway, I claim that *los ratones cuidaban a las serpientes* would be clearly correct; *los ratones les cuidaban a las serpientes* sounds correct in "my" dialect if we're pretending that the snakes are [funny animals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funny_animal) in the Beatrix Potter tradition; *¿Qué hacían los ratones con las serpientes? Las cuidaban.* would be correct; and repeating the direct object *los ratones las cuidaban a las serpientes* would be unnatural in anyone's dialect AFAIK.